# Compare two files of different columns and print different columns

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I want to compare 2nd column of *file2* with 1st column of *file1*. If they are equal i want to add the 2nd column of *file1* to *file2* as shown in *output.txt*.

*file2*

```
chr5    ENST00000514151    utr5    0    +
chr5    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
chr5    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
chr5    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
```

*file1*

```
ENST00000512281    a
ENST00000504031    b
ENST00000776348    c
```

*output.txt*

```
chr5    a    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
chr5    a    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
chr5    a    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
```

I was able compare the files with

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$2 in a{print}' file1 file2
```

This gives below output:

```
chr5    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
chr5    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
chr5    ENST00000512281    utr5    0    +
```

But I do not know how to add the 2nd colum of file1 into the output.

Comment: Why is there no `chr5 b ENST00000504031 utr5 0 +` in the required output?

Comment: Thanks @Håkon Hægland, i have 2 removed  lines in the file2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the value of `$2` in `file1` into the array using `a[$1]=$2`. So you could try:

```
awk '
   NR==FNR{ 
     a[$1]=$2 ; next }
   $2 in a {
     $1=$1 FS a[$2]
     print 
   }' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
chr5 b ENST00000504031 utr5 0 +
chr5 b ENST00000504031 utr5 0 +
chr5 a ENST00000512281 utr5 0 +
chr5 a ENST00000512281 utr5 0 +
chr5 a ENST00000512281 utr5 0 +
```

**Explanation:**

- This modifies `$1` in `file2` using `$1=$1 FS a[$2]` where `FS` is the default field separator, which is a space.. and then rebuilds the record, such that it can be printed by `print` later..
- The `print` can be simplified to a `1` if desired.. Like `$2 in a { $1=$1 FS a[$2] }1`
- Note that this rebuilds the record in `file2` and thus any sequences of spaces or tabs will be truncated to a single space in the output. To keep the original formatting in `file2` one could use the `split()` function in Gnu Awk version 4..

Comment: Hi @Håkon Hægland, I'm getting a error while executing `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$2 in a {$1=$1 FS a[$2] print }' file1 file2` it's not working

Comment: Thanks @Håkon Hægland,what needs to be done if i want to print the 2nd column of file 1 in output.txt as third column. Just curious

Comment: You are welcome. I think you can just replace `$1` with `$2` in  `$1=$1 FS a[$2]` to move it to the third column instead of the second.. (i.e.: `$2=$2 FS a[$2]`)